# when set to auto, width of a block element not transitioning

Tags: jquery, html, css, width, transition

I have the following html structure

`<div class=outer>
    <div class=inner></div>
<div>`

The width of .inner is auto and changes according the text I put in it using JQuery. I want the width of .outer, or .inner, to change smoothly when the text content inside .inner changes. I have written the following CSS code

```
.outer {
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

.inner {
        transition: all 0.5s linear; // just to be sure
        background-color: white;
        color: @body;
        display: block;
        padding: 18px 28px;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
}
```

Now the behavior is that the width changes instantly, without the slightest transition. I want the width to change smoothly. The transition is added via LESS, so I am ok with prefixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS transitions don't work on values such as `auto` since it has no meaning behind it except for using the default behaviour or resetting something however percentages can be animated.

I created an animated loader using just CSS and percentage widths for an inner element however my element has fixed dimensions as in it knows the minimum width in percent and the maximum width in percent so those two values can be calculated.

Animating from 100% to auto would require a little more effort, if you do not know the dimensions after manipulating the element (for instance it scales down automatically) you'd have to create an invisible element with a display so that you can find out how wide it is to then remove it again.

Instead of having an `auto` value you could use `100%` for maximum width and a minimum percentage value to transition to.